# 'cannot be cast to' error in custom adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have a application with slidemenu that have some fragments in it

two custom adapter i used that both of them are same code and just one of them have a image more than another

customadapter file is:

```
package ir.monocode.az;

import ir.monocode.az.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/********* Adapter class extends with BaseAdapter and implements with OnClickListener ************/
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

    /*********** Declare Used Variables *********/
    private Context activity;
    private ArrayList data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public Resources res;
    CatsModel tempValues=null;
    int i=0;
    Context context; 
    Typeface face;

    /*************  CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList d,Resources resLocal) {

        /********** Take passed values **********/
        activity = context;
        data=d;
        res = resLocal;

        /***********  Layout inflator to call external xml layout () **********************/
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    /******** What is the size of Passed Arraylist Size ************/
    public int getCount() {

        if(data.size()<=0)
            return 1;
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /********* Create a holder to contain inflated xml file elements ***********/
    public static class ViewHolder{

        public TextView text;
        public ImageView image;

    }

    /*********** Depends upon data size called for each row , Create each ListView row ***********/
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vii=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){ 

            /********** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) ************/
            vii = inflater.inflate(R.layout.catitems, null); 


            /******** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ************/
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.text=(TextView)vii.findViewById(R.id.ctextView1);
            holder.image=(ImageView)vii.findViewById(R.id.cimageView2);

            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(holder.text.getContext().getAssets(),
                    "fonts/B YEKAN.TTF");
            holder.text.setTypeface(typeface);
            /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            vii.setTag(holder);
        }
        else  
            holder=(ViewHolder)vii.getTag();

        if(data.size()<=0)
        {
            holder.text.setText("No Data");

        }
        else
        {
            /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
            tempValues=null;
            tempValues = (CatsModel) data.get(position);

            /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/
             holder.text.setText(tempValues.getCatName());
             int resID = activity.getResources().getIdentifier("icon"+tempValues.getImage() , "drawable", activity.getPackageName());
             holder.image.setImageResource(resID);

             /******** Set Item Click Listener for LayoutInflater for each row ***********/
             vii.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
        }
        return vii;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("CustomAdapter", "=====Row button clicked");


    }

    /********* Called when Item click in ListView ************/
    private class OnItemClickListener  implements OnClickListener{           
        private int mPosition;

        OnItemClickListener(int position){
         mPosition = position;
       }

       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
           MainActivity sct = (MainActivity)activity;
        sct.customonItemClick(mPosition);

       }



    }   
}
```

articleadapter is:

```
package ir.monocode.az;

import ir.monocode.azmoonEstekhdami.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

/********* Adapter class extends with BaseAdapter and implements with OnClickListener ************/
public class ArticleAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

    /*********** Declare Used Variables *********/
    private Context activity;
    private ArrayList data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public Resources res;
    ArticlesModel tempValues=null;
    int i=0;
    Context context; 
    Typeface face;

    /*************  CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
    public ArticleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList d,Resources resLocal) {

        /********** Take passed values **********/
        activity = context;
        data=d;
        res = resLocal;

        /***********  Layout inflator to call external xml layout () **********************/
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    /******** What is the size of Passed Arraylist Size ************/
    public int getCount() {

        if(data.size()<=0)
            return 1;
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /********* Create a holder to contain inflated xml file elements ***********/
    public static class ViewHolder{

        public TextView text;

    }

    /*********** Depends upon data size called for each row , Create each ListView row ***********/
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){ 

            /********** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) ************/
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.articleitems, null); 


            /******** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ************/
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.atextView1);

            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(holder.text.getContext().getAssets(),
                    "fonts/B YEKAN.TTF");
            holder.text.setTypeface(typeface);
            /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else  
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        if(data.size()<=0)
        {
            holder.text.setText("No Data");

        }
        else
        {
            /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
            tempValues=null;
            tempValues = (ArticlesModel) data.get(position);

            /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/
             holder.text.setText(tempValues.getArticleName());


        }
        return vi;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("CustomAdapter", "=====Row button clicked");


    }

    /********* Called when Item click in ListView ************/
    private class OnItemClickListener  implements OnClickListener{           
        private int mPosition;

        OnItemClickListener(int position){
         mPosition = position;
       }

       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
           MainActivity sct = (MainActivity)activity;
        sct.articleItemClick(mPosition);

       }

    }


}
```

and of course i have two xml layout for my items style:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cLinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cLinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ctextView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#215e76"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cimageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:maxHeight="20dp"
            android:maxWidth="20dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cimageView1"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffc20e" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and another is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/aLinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/aLinearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/atextView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#215e76"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/aimageView1"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffc20e" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

now when i run program
fragment that fill with customadapter work very good
but fragment that filled by articlesadapter have below error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: ir.monocode.az.ArticlesModel cannot be cast to ir.monocode.az.CatsModel
```

how i must solve my problem?
can you help me please?
thank you

Comment: I'd suggest that you edit the question so that the class cast error message is near the top, so that people immediately see what the problem is, and then decide whether to look at the code. Also, try not to write as if you're in a kiddie chatroom, i.e. use caps when needed. And post a few more lines from the stack trace, if available. All this will bring you more success here :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve with polymorphism. Replace the failing declaration (the one your cast error comes from) with the Interface `BaseAdapter`

Something like this (your relevant code wasn't posted, so this is just a guess)

```
CatsModel it = retrieveMyCustomAdapter();
```

becomes

```
 BaseAdapter it = retrieveMyCustomAdapter();
```

A more formal approach would be to declare an abstract class extending BaseAdapter, and make both CatsModel and ArticlesModel inherit from this new class.